# Query WKT from BLOB in mysql

Tags: mysql-spatial

I am trying to query a table in MySQL which contains spatial data. Out of all the columns, I have one column called "pt". Each entry in this field is specified as 'BLOB'. In my MySQL workbench 6.3,when I right click on any of these entries, it takes me to Open Value in Viewer where I can see my data as POINT(X,Y) in Text/WKT format.I am interested to query this data using python but do not know the syntax. Could someone please help?

Comment: What kind of query are you thinking of constructing? What type of information are you going looking to extract? My first inclination is that you want to use arcpy.SearchCursor: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/specifying-a-query.htm

Comment: I want to extract this BLOB data which is given as for example POINT(31300 249349) using a mysql query such as SELECT etc.